# Solving a recurrence with substitution method the having a square root in it

Tags: algorithm

How would you go about with solving a recurrence relation with the substitution method that has square root like
`T(n) = 4T(n/2) + sqrt(n)`
Also, how would you draw a recursion tree for it?

Comment: (Assuming this is in the context of asymptotic analysis) the "master theorem" applies in this case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms) . It may be easier to see if "sqrt(n)" is written as "n^(1/2)".

Comment: It’s hard to make a good guess on this recurrence, the master theorem would be perfect to solve this. As for the height of the tree, it is *log n*. And the tight bound is *θ(n ^ 2)*.